# Audio on website - working crossbrowser AND on iPhone - with cues

Tags: html, ios, iphone, audio, html5-audio

I've been googling like crazy and I can't find anything suiting my level of knowledge.

I need to have a long (mp3/ogg) audio file playing on my website and I **need some way to let a visitor click on links/buttons that will move the playhead to certain positions**.

It is not an optimal solution to break the audio apart because it needs to be playable seemlessly without interruption. So I need something like ID-/Chapter-points or CUE-points that can be called/activated by the visitor. AND I'd like it to be **usable on (fairly recent) browsers including Safari on iPhone/iPad**.

*HTML track Tag* seems promising but according to W3schools it is not supported by Safari - and that leaves iPad/iPhony out.

So I am hoping that someone could direct me to a useful tutorial - preferably at a for-dummies level.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer!

I found a method to use cuepoints via javascript/jquery-plug-in called cuepoint.js. So here's hoping other users may find the same soultion usable :-)

Cuepoint.js lets you add and define cuepoints (and subtitles) to HTML5 video and -audio.

(The link used to be http://cuepoint.org/ but that leads nowhere any longer. But googling cuepoint.js still yields usable results)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.